# iptables : command not found

Tags: iptables

I am trying to learn some `iptables` stuff,  but seems I don't have it installed on 16.04 Ubuntu.

```
mypc@ubuntu:~$ iptables
-bash: iptables: command not found
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iptables` needs a root priviledges. Seems like you are trying to execute it as a normal user.

so: `sudo iptables`

Also, check are iptables loaded in the kernel:

`lsmod | grep ip_tables`